# python regular expression help

Tags: python, regex

Need to match any string ends up with a letter, and the second last character is '>'

It will match:

```
abc>a
ddd_4>f
```

It will not match:

```
abc>ab
abc>2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'abc>a'
>>> r = re.compile(r'>[:alpha:]$')
>>> print( r.search(s) )
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb76c5a30>
>>>
```

If you want to match letters according to locales.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.compile(r'.*>[a-zA-Z]$')
```

should generate the pattern that you want.

However, I recommend that you take a read through the [regexp part](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html) of [Google's Python class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/index.html). Then you can learn how to do things like this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`.*>[a-zA-Z]$`

```
>>> for s in ('abc>a', 'ddd_4>f', 'abc>ab', 'abc>2'):
...     print re.match(r'.*>[a-zA-Z]$', s)
... 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7217e58>
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7217e58>
None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import re 
re.search(">[a-zA-Z]$", str)
```

It will evaluate to `None` if the string does not match.